# Is there a notation for the operator $(\frac{\partial}{\partial u_x},\frac{\partial}{\partial u_y})^T$?

Tags: calculus, notation, vector-analysis

I know that the operator $\nabla$ denotes
$$
\nabla = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there some kind of similar notation to denote

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial}{\partial u_x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial u_y} \end{pmatrix}
$$

where $u_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u$, likewise $u_y$. Here $u$ denotes some differentiable function in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Like the gradient on the fibre of the tangent bundle?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but the directional derivative along a vector field $\mathbf v = (v_x, v_y)$ is usually denoted $(\mathbf v \cdot \nabla)$, which means $v_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + v_y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. This is used to define the [material derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative) in continuum mechanics.

Comment: @Rahul, No, I'm looking for a shorthand for $$A = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial v_x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial v_y}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common to use the notation $\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}$ for gradient with respect to the velocity field. An alternative notation is $\partial/\partial{\mathbf{u}}$ so that the usual gradient is written as $\partial/\partial{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: If I applied $\nabla_{\bf{u}} f$ wouldn't I get $\langle \nabla f, \bf{u} \rangle $?

Comment: No, you should get $\hat{e}_x\partial f/\partial u_x + \hat{e}_y\partial f/\partial u_y$ in two dimensions.

Comment: But couldn't $\nabla_\bf{u}$ be confused with the directional derivative?

Comment: I did mean the directional derivative. I gave an analog of the nabla operator. If it is not a directional derivative with respect to a velocity field, why would want to write it as a vector. Can you possible write an expression in a long form that you want to write in a compact notation?

Comment: Euler Lagrange equations are an example. I want ti write to gradient wrt a different basis I think (instead of the canonical basis I'd use the velocity field I think).

Comment: You can write Euler-Lagrange equations in this form.

Comment: So assuming one unknown function $y$ I could write $$0 = D_y \mathcal{L} - \nabla^T \cdot \nabla_\bf{u} \mathcal{L}, $$ correct?

Comment: I don't think I recognize this form of Euler-Lagrange equations. But if $x, y, z$ are the generalized coordinates and $v_x, v_y, v_z$ the generalized velocities, then one can write $$\nabla L - \frac{d}{dt}\nabla_\mathbf{v}L = 0$$.

Comment: I believe there was a mistake in my question, I didn't mean "velocities" but "partial derivatives".